# Center a list of users

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code

```css
.selection_user {
  display: block;
  background-color: #2D2C31;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_user_menu">
  <div class="selection_user">User1</div>
  <div class="selection_user">Username</div>
  <div class="selection_user">User</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is center the list of users in one line.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, if you want the text to be left aligned, why you have `text-align: center`?

Comment: Between the title and your description I don't understand what you want or what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make another div element inside and then use `Flexbox` on parent element.

```css
.select_user_menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.selection_user {
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_user_menu">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="selection_user">User1</div>
    <div class="selection_user">Username</div>
    <div class="selection_user">User</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't add a background to the users?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the three usernames into a wrapper element to which you assign `display: inline-block;` apply `text-align: center` to the outer container to center that wrapper and `text-align: left;` to the child elements to left-align the text in there:

```css
.select_user_menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.select_user_menu>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.selection_user {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_user_menu">
  <div>
    <div class="selection_user">User1</div>
    <div class="selection_user">Username</div>
    <div class="selection_user">User</div>
  </div>
</div>
```